# AWS S3 Bucket - File Explorer Field

Tags: entities, files

I'm looking for a file field module that will allow me to select files from an AWS S3 Bucket, but not upload them.

A client of mine is going to be uploading csv files via ftp from a different location and he wants users of a lesser role to be able to select the files from within the website.

I know that Scald will probably serve those needs, but not without a lot of setup and headaches.

Anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a read only access for your users, correct?
It's not so difficult to implement in Amazon S3.

First of all, you need to set up an IAM user and apply read only permissions for it. AWS provides pre-defined policy template. More information here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/

Once you created a user, you can connect to your storage using tools such as CloudBerry Explorer. When you client authanticats using key pairs assigned to the read only user you created, they will be able only to download files.
You can download CloudBerry Explroer here:
http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx

Regards,
Vlad,
CloudBerry Lab

Comment: Thank you for the info, but I'm specifically looking for a Drupal field solution for this.

Within Drupal, users should be able to pick a file, and NOT be able to upload. I need something like a file browser that is linked to a directory on the S3.